# A child’s toy is made by fixing a solid right circular cone, with base radius $r$ cm and height $h$

Tags: calculus

A child’s toy is made by fixing a solid right circular cone, with base radius $r$ cm and height $h$ cm, on the flat circular face of a solid hemisphere of radius $r$ cm. The centre of the base of the cone coincides with the centre of the hemisphere, as shown in Figure

[image]

Given that $~h + 6r = 15~$.

Find the upper bound for the value of $r$. Give a reason for your answer.

Comment: attempts ? sticking points ?

Comment: the answer is r=2.5 but i cannot understand how this value came

Comment: r grows as h shrinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone's trying to get us to do their math homework.

Here, we're very simply just letting the limit of $h$ go to 0, which for this context gives us $h = 0$. $0 + 6r = 15$, simple algebra from there.

Comment: No sir, it's just tomorrow is my IGCSE and i'm helpless at this point that I cannot meet my teacher before my exam. Thanks alot for the help but can u tell why does the limit of h go to 0? would appreciate the help

Comment: $6r$ needs to be as large as possible for $r$ to be. that needs $15-h$ to be maximal, which happens as $h$ is minimal. a minimal length is 0.